# Changing the whole application theme dynamically

Tags: android-activity, themes, android-theme, android

I found many ways to change the activities theme dynamically.
But I use some chart and graph from aChartengine that can't change their theme, because they are not just like activities.
So, I need to find out a way to change app theme dynamically so that also my charts theme will change too!

I wonder if someone can solve this problem.

This is my code, which works on each activity:

```
public class Utils
{
    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
    public final static int THEME_PINK = 3;

    /**
     * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity
     * of the same type.
     */
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        sTheme = theme;

        activity.finish();

        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));

    }

    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (sTheme)
        {
        default:
        case THEME_DEFAULT:
            break;
        case THEME_WHITE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_white);
            break;
        case THEME_BLUE:
            Log.i("THM", "blue intered in utils");
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_blue);
            break;
        case THEME_PINK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_pink);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this code to change my activity theme:

```
Utils.changeToTheme(G.tabActivity, Utils.THEME_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your current theme in `SharedPreferences` and apply it on start of your app:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("your_pref_name", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String theme = pref.getString("your_pref_key", "your_default_theme");
context.setTheme(theme);
```

Then, when you change your theme you should restart application:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: as you can see in my code i  restart the activity to affect the theme. but problem is my all theme are set to the activities one by one with `Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);`  and there is no solution to set the theme to the app